# How to add element in ArrayList<? extends SomeType> via a method

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

i want to add element extending Type to ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<? extends Type>
```

i defined a method as below

```
public <T extends Type> void addItem(T itemToAdd, Class<?> classType) {
    ArrayList<? extends Type> allItems = getAllItems(classType);
    allItems.add(itemToAdd);
}
```

T itemToAdd is error. because i can't add someother type. i thought  but i don't know to mention it and its error!

How to add the item via a method call?

Comment: Is it a typo that you have both `SomeType` and `Type` in your question?

Comment: no i've the correct type in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about your definition: `ArrayList<? extends Type>`. It means list of elements each of them extends `Type`. It does not mean that each of them is of type `T` as `itemToAdd`. To make this code to compile you have to ensure this fact, i.e. use `T` in all relevant places:

```
public <T extends Type> void addItem(T itemToAdd, Class<T> classType) {
    List<T> allItems = getAllItems(classType);
    allItems.add(itemToAdd);
}
```

It probably means that you should change definition of `getAllItem()` to

```
public <T extends Type> List<T> getAllItems(Class<T> classType)
```

BTW please pay attention that I changed your `ArrayList` to `List`. Although it is out of the topic but avoid using concrete classes at the left part of assignment operator, as a return value of method and as a method parameter.

Comment: so wherever we mention T, eg: List<T> it means that it returns a list of <T extends Type> ?

Comment: Exactly. But `T` is always the same over whole the way.

Comment: but when i'm calling function everytime i need to pass class<T> also anyway to eliminate that? just like calling <Type>method()?

Comment: You do not need it for method `addItem`. You *probably* need it for `getAllItems` but since you have not shared code of this method I cannot say whether you can eliminate this parameter. Try to ask another question and share more code.

Answer (score 0):

If you define  for your List all object must have the same type

If you want to insert multiple class defined simple List and you can insert objects extends Type

Example :

```
List<Type> list = gellAllItems(class);
list.add(T);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your declaration of the return value of `getAllItems`, but you can't put `itemToAdd` with type `T extends Type` into `ArrayList<? extends Type>`. The type of element may be unmatch (different type although both are the derived class of `Type`), so the `ArrayList` should be declared as

```
ArrayList<? super Type> allItems;
```

which can guarantee `itmeToAdd` can be put into the `ArrayList`, or just:

```
ArrayList<Type> allItems;
```